# NSDateFormatter stringFromDate returning empty string

Tags: objective-c

Here's how I'm setting it up:

```
self.df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[self.df setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[self.df setDateFormat:@"posted: MM-dd-YYYY"];
```

Here is how I am calling it in my trace:

```
 NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@, %@", df, post.date, [post.date class], [df stringFromDate:post.date]);
```

Here's the output:

```
<NSDateFormatter: 0x8440d60>, 2012-02-09 12:40:38 +0000, __NSDate,
```

It's not null, it's "".

The post class with the date property is autogenerated by core data. I can't see how that makes a difference, but it's the only thing that seems even slightly unusual.

Comment: Put a printout for the post.date, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use setDateFormat like that.

I tried this code and it worked:

```
[self.df setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY"];
```

Now, you can do:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"posted:%@", [df stringFromDate:post.date]];
```

Comment: Thanks, @tonio.mg, it was indeed the stray "posted:" in the format string.

It turns out you can escape the text with single quotes in the format string, so this also works:

    [self.df setDateFormat:@"'posted: 'MM-dd-YYYY"];